# HatchFilling becomes gray for small aspect ratio Rectangles

Tags: graphics, bugs

I am trying to use the new to version 12.1 graphics directive `HatchFilling`. Here is an example:

```
Column@Table[Graphics[{
    {
     {HatchFilling[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, y}]},
     Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]
     }
    },
   PlotLabel -> "Aspect Ratio = " <> ToString[y]],
  {y, {0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see when the aspect ratio is small the hatching is gray but then becomes blacker as the aspect ratio goes towards 1. I don't want it to change gray level. (`GrayLevel` has no effect).

Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a bug, but perhaps a workaround: `Column@Table[Graphics[{{{HatchFilling[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, y}]}, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}}, PlotRangePadding -> {0, 0.2}], {y, {0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1}}]`. I don't know why this works but maybe it can help.

Comment: I'm encountering this problem in version 13 right now while trying to add color to the hatches. The red is most prominent when the aspect ratio is 1 and is basically just grey at the smaller values: https://imgur.com/YVldmCW

Comment: Using PatternFilling with a custom pattern and messing with ImageScaled is a work around.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I will try and send a bug report to Wolfram.